# C# Web Service "Remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, system.net.webexception

I'm using a web reference in a c# Windows Forms application.

I have two servers that I'm connecting to using a SOAP web service. Each server has its own domain name (e.g. one is abcd.co.uk, the other abcd.tv).

I can set up both web services in the Visual Studio IDE with no problems. The problem occurs when I try to connect to the SOAP service on the .tv server. Now, previously this had a .org domain name and it connected fine. Since changing it to the .tv domain, it doesn't.

The error is a System.Net.WebException "The remote name could not be resolved: 'abcd.tvindex.php.

And that's the problem - on the .org and .co.uk domains, it keeps the slash between the extension and index.php (i.e. abcd.org/index.php). On the .tv one, the created wsdl file and settings.settings files both remove the slash so it tries to connect to abcd.tvindex.php. I can edit those files but somewhere, it still keeps the address without the slash and never connects.

Is this a known issue? Is a .tv domain no good / not known or understodd by .NET? Or maybe the problem is on the Apache server side?

Thank you for any help

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the WSDL (or a URL to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wsdl file is created server side.  If it doesn't have the correct slashes in it, then it is a problem with the server.

Comment: That's perfect. The server side wsdl file did have an error in it. Thank you very much.